# android passing String array and String to asyncTask

Tags: java, android, parameters, android-asynctask

I would like to pass String array and String variable to my AsyncTask class. I am new to programming android apps so It is possible that this is not the most efficient way to achieve my goal. Anyways, I have String array called separate[] and String selected.

In separate[] I have loaded values from EditText View and in selected, there is a value from my spinner. Now I want to work with these in my AsyncTask. My AsyncTask class looks now like this:

```
 final class cyklus extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, String[]>{
String[] tones = {"C","Cis","D","Dis","E","F","Fis","G","Gis","A","Ais","B"};
String[] result;

@Override
protected String[] doInBackground(String[]... params) {

    int l =params.length;  //length of separate[]

    for(int k=0; k==l; k++){   // finding indexes of matches of elements separate[k] in tones[] 

        // INPUT POSITION
                int i= Arrays.asList(tones).indexOf(params[k]);


        // RESULT INDEX
                int j =Integer.parseInt(selected);
                int index = i+j;    


        // RESULT
                String res=tones[index];
                result[k]=res;                          

}

    return result;
}
 }
```

After this for loop is done, I would like my AsyncTask to return result[]. To sum up tis, I would like to know how can I work with "separate[]" and "selected" in my AsyncTask class. Thank you.

EDIT: One more subquestion. My for loop wont start. Why? Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Change your method to look like this:defined globally

```
String[] tones = {"C","Cis","D","Dis","E","F","Fis","G","Gis","A","Ais","B"};
```

now, call your Async task like below:

```
new cyklus().execute(tones);
```

And now, change your Async task implementation

```
public class cyklus extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, String[]> {
ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setTitle("Calculating...");
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    dialog.show();
}

protected String[] doInBackground(String[]... passing) {
    String[] result = new String[10];
    String[] passed = passing[0]; //get passed array

    //Some calculations...

    return result; //return result
}

protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    String minim = result.get(0);
}
```

This is how you implement AsyncTask. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you, but I think we didnt understand each other :). I dont need to pass my tones[] in. I need to pass one string variable: String selected and String[] separate, where in String selected, there is value from my spinner and in String[] separate, there are values from my EditText. String selected is declared in my onCreate method. How can I do this?

Comment: @user2886091 so you want pass a string value alright and what you want get return back from AsyncTask?

Comment: I want to pass String[] separate and String selected at the same time. I want my AsyncTask to return String[] result.

Comment: Create a AsyncTask Constructor with Two Argument. Have a look into @ohntheripp3r Answer below

Answer (score 1):

Create a asynctask constructor like this

```
public class Blah extends AsyncTask<... , ... , ...>
{
     String one;
     String[] two;
     public Blah(String one, String[] two)
     {
         this.one = one;
         this.two = two;
     }
     onPreExe.....
     doInBack....
     onPostExe....
 }
```

From Activity

`Blah b = new Blah("abc", new String[]{"a", "b","c"};`
`b.execute(...);`

Answer (score 1):

Write a constructor and pass values using it.

```
    public cyklus(Context context,String[] tones){
    this.context = context;
    this.tones = tones;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know from where **selected** value is coming in

```
// RESULT INDEX
int j =Integer.parseInt(selected);
```

But you can set the result like this by adding onPostExecute()

```
    final class cyklus extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, String[]> {
    String[] tones = { "C", "Cis", "D", "Dis", "E", "F", "Fis", "G", "Gis",
            "A", "Ais", "B" };
    String[] result;

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String[]... params) {

        int l = params.length; // length of separate[]

        for (int k = 0; k == l; k++) { // finding indexes of matches of
                                        // elements separate[k] in tones[]

            // INPUT POSITION
            int i = Arrays.asList(tones).indexOf(params[k]);

            // RESULT INDEX
            int j = Integer.parseInt(selected);
            int index = i + j;

            // RESULT
            String res = tones[index];
            result[k] = res;

        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Set the result array to what ever object u want to
    }
}
```

Comment: That is the thing I am asking. String selected is declared in my onCreate method and in this varieble, there is value from my spinner. So I need to pass in String selected and String[] separate. Can u help me with this please?